# Why new Date doesn't work in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript

I want to check difference between given date and now. I want to use exactly the code below and it works fine in chrome. but the console log says something else in Firefox.

Why? and how to fix this?

```js
// input your custom Date below
const date = new Date('2020-6-23 14:22:00 GMT+0430'); // Set End Time Here!
const dif = (date.getTime() / 1000) - ((new Date().getTime())/1000);
const end = Math.max(0, dif);

console.log(date, dif, end);
```

Comment: I tested and it didn't work, like you said, but I think the problem is with the time zone, if you remove if from the string when creating the date - everything works

Comment: Firefox doesn't like strings being passed to date that have the timezone. Change your time zone accordingly in the below code. Also note the T in the date/time

const date = new Date('2020-6-23T14:22:00'); date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })

Comment: I want Tehran GMT.

Comment: That is why I mentioned that you would need to my code but change the Timezone accordingly.

Comment: Tehran GMT is a misnomer. You should not specify "GMT". The string should be in ISO 8601 format to be certain that it gets parsed correctly. Remove "GMT" and the space before it. BTW: GMT is an ambiguous term anyway. UTC is a more exact defined term.

Comment: Guy please, Can you prepare an answer...

Comment: Use one of the two standardized date string forms that Date.parse is supposed to accept, ISO variant or the toString variant.  Don't use these non-standard date time strings, unless you will validate and parse them yourself.

Comment: The question is opened again :)

Comment: try using ISO8601 format instead, ```new Date("2020-06-23T14:22:00+04:30");``` , also there's no need to create a new Date object to get the current time, just use `Date.now()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"GMT" does not belong in that string. The string should be [ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521864/why-new-date-doesnt-work-in-firefox-browser#) compliant, if you want to be sure that it gets parsed correctly.

To align it with the ISO standard:

- remove "GMT" and the space before it,
- separate the time part from the date part with a "T",
- write the month with double digits.
- Either use punctuation (hyphen, colon) in the date, time **and** timezone, or don't use any at all. This condition is not really clear in the ISO 8601 specs I have access to, but apparently there is a move towards a more strict definition which excludes using punctuation only in a part of the string. In short, you are sure to align when you add also a colon in `+04:30`.

```js
const date = new Date('2020-06-23T14:22:00+04:30');

// Now also output it in the Iranian timezone:
console.log(date.toLocaleString("en", { timeZone: "Iran" } ));
```

BTW: GMT is an ambiguous term anyway. UTC is a more exact defined term.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216493/discussion-on-answer-by-trincot-why-new-date-doesnt-work-in-firefox-browser).